# MySQL 5.6 GET DIAGNOSTICS into log table and ROLLBACK previous DML

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Apparently I cannot combine the GET DIAGNOSTICS and ROLLBACK statements inside a stored procedure: besides catching the error, I want to be able to reverse all the previous processed data, not just to stop the execution. Please find bellow my script:

- Create the log table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_logs (

`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`txt` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

- Create the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`() 

BEGIN 

DECLARE state CHAR(5) DEFAULT ’00000′;

DECLARE msg TEXT;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 

begin 

   rollback;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 state = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;

   insert into tbl_logs (txt) select concat(‘Error ‘,state,’: ‘,msg);

 end;

start transaction; 

   insert into tbl_logs (txt) select state;

   – drop table no_such_table;

   insert into tbl_logs (txt) select ‘commit’; 

commit; 

END
```

- call the procedure:

```
call test(); 

select * from tbl_logs;
```

=> check the table: 2 rows

**00000**

**commit**

---

- Alter the procedure:

  Take the comment out, making the drop table visible.

---

- call the procedure:

```
call test();

select * from tbl_logs;
```

=> check the table: 2 new rows instead of just one, the last

**00000**

**Error 42S02: Unknown table ‘no_such_table’**

---

=> the handler catches the error and stops the execution, is just that doesn’t consider the rollback (no matter what/where other DML are previously made, they are committed)…

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [`DROP TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/drop-table.html):

> #### Note
>
> [`DROP TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/drop-table.html) automatically commits the current active transaction, unless you use the `TEMPORARY` keyword.